# How can I share an album publicly (i.e. with non-icloud users) on iCloud

Tags: icloud, photos, photos.app

Using "Photos" Version 1.0 (209.52.0) that just got "put" on my computer at last update. Here's what my share menu looks like:

[image: "Share album" flyout menu with the following fields: Shared Album Name, To, and Comment. Disabled "create" button as well.]

Here's the [support page](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH12068?locale=en_US) where I looked for help.

**Goal**: expose photo album via a URL I can copy/paste to people.

Answer (score 4):

Share it with the person - then once the album is created, in Photos, there will be an icon with a head in a circle. This is the settings pane for the shared photo album.

Full Procedure:

1. Create Shared iCloud Album
2. Select new Shared Album from left side pane in Photos
3. Click head in a circle icon to get an option to turn on the Public Website.
4. Check that box and it gives you the URL.

Sample:

[image: Album Options pane]

Not obvious, but it works.